# What does "them" in "eat one of them" refer to?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

In *How to Train Your Dragon The Hidden World* (2019), Ruffnut talks unstop:

> Ruffnut: Snotlout's a beefcake but almost too pretty, you know?
>   Sometimes I think he's more in love with himself than me. There's only
>   room for one beauty in this relationship. Fishlegs would keep me alive
>   longer if I had to **eat one of  them**, stranded on some glacier
>   somewhere. But he never shuts  up about dragons.

What does "them"  in "eat one of  them" refer to?

Comment: One of them, his friends, presumably. That out of all of them, Fishlegs is the fattest and hence the obvious choice of potential glacier companion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ruffnut Eugene Thorston](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Ruffnut_Thorston) is rambling on non-stop, whether by her nature or by design to irritate her jailer. Her current diatribe is regarding the pros and cons of choosing a potential mate from the male members of the [Dragon Riders](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon_Riders). After discounting [Eret, Son of Eret](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Eret,_Son_of_Eret) and [Hiccup Haddock](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Hiccup_Horrendous_Haddock_III_(Franchise)) for various reasons, she focuses on [Snotlout Jorgenson](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Snotlout_Jorgenson) and [Fishlegs Ingerman](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Fishlegs_Ingerman).

> RUFFNUT: All the boys love me. **Except Eret**, who totally lost his chance. That ship has sailed, boys, sorry. And **Hiccup is practically married** to that round head, Astrid. **But Snotlout and Fishlegs, they're basically in my hand.**
>
> *(Grimmel's pencil snaps and he becomes even more annoyed. Ruffnut is now swinging upside down.)*
>
> RUFFNUT: Just can't choose, you know. Snotlout's a beefcake but almost too pretty, you know. Sometimes I think he's more in love with himself than me. There's only room for one beauty in this relationship. (laughs and walks to cage bars between her and a Scuttleclaw's cage) **Fishlegs would keep me alive longer if I had to eat one of them**. Stranded on some glacier somewhere. But he never shuts up about dragons. Do you hate it when people never stop talking?
>
> GRIMMEL: Yyyeeessss, I dooo.
>   <sub>*source:* [How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World (transcript)](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_Train_Your_Dragon:_The_Hidden_World_(transcript))</sub>

[image]

          <sub>*(left to right)* Fishlegs Ingerman, Ruffnut Thorston and Snotlout_Jorgenson</sub>

[Fishlegs Ingerman](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Fishlegs_Ingerman) is physically the largest in the group. According to her abstract reasoning and despite his other shortcomings, he would provide more food (i.e. cannibalism) if the two were stranded on a glacier somewhere.

So the **them** in *"eat one of them"* is **Snotlout and Fishlegs**.

---